# Javascripts that detects mobile browser (and redirect) inside of SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, windows-mobile

Can anybody tell me the javascript that detects if the web browser is mobile and redirect to diffent page (if it is mobile browser) inside of SharePoint (Content Editor Web part)?

I think I need a javascript for that where I can put it in the source editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you can always ask for the `navigator` and check diferent properties like `navigator.userAgent` that will give you something like this

User-agent header: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7

```
That string you can search deviceIphone, deviceIpod for mac devices and so on for the different browsers.
```

You can use something like this http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ to avoid checking manualy each diferent movile provider, but sometimes is good to make especific pages for some devices.

You can also check diferent browsers serverside and make a redirect before.